# Start an app from a running background service

Tags: android

Just wondering if its possible to launch an install application from a background service. I have the packagename as well.

Answer (score 2):

An installed application can be invoked using PackageManager class

```
startActivity(BackgroundService.this.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can launch an activity from a service.

Comment: Thank you very much. I achieved this by using startActivity() Is there a way to close it after a certain amount of time?

Comment: If its a short amount of time (a few seconds max), use a handler with a delayed message, and start the activity there.  If its a long time later, use an alarm so it happens even if the screen is off.

Comment: I have successfully started the application from my service, now after a certain amount of time, how would I close it?

Comment: Call stopService on the same intent you used to start it.

Comment: Calling stopService on the same intent is failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package_name");
startActivity( intent);
```

For more information you can see [package manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and [getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can launch an activity from a service. use this code this is worked for me

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(mIntent);
```

don't forget to called `mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` otherwise its gives error